# Size of contents inside a div should be respective to it's parent div

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a div, with max-width as 40% & max-height as 25%. Inside this there is an image. I wanted the image size to be 80% of it's parent div. Below code is for reference.

```
 <div className="inputbox-container">
        <img className="inputbox-icon" src={icon}/>
        <input
            className="inputFeild"
            placeholder="Email Id"
        />
       </div>
```

scss

```
.inputbox-container {
    background-color: red;
    max-width: 40%;
    max-height: 25%;
    border: 0.5px solid grey;
    border-radius: 7px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.inputbox-icon {
    height: 80%;
}
```

Due to the height of `.inputbox-icon` as 80%, the image become 80% of the screen size. Also the `.inputbox-container` height became 800px. How can I make the size of the contents to be relative to the parent's size. If `input-container` occupies is 25% of the screen then the image in it should occupy the 80% of the `input-container`.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution!**

Use `.css` **extension** in your **styling file** for example `style.css` the solution code in give below with following solution image.
image of solution: [Solution image as you want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBE4k.png)
image explanation: As you said you want your **image should be 80% height** of your **container 25% height**. So you have to set the height of the container explicitly using `height: 25vh;` 25vh = 25% or you can modify as you needed in your design here is code given below

```css
.container {
  max-width: 40%;
  height: 25vh;
  /* 25% of the viewport height also Adjust the value based on your design */
  border: 5px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  border-radius: 7px;
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.container>.image {
  width: auto;
  height: 80%;
  max-width: 100%;
  /* Ensure the image doesn't exceed the width of the container */
}

.container>input {
  height: min-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img class="image" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/The-Codar/web_development_projects_practice/main/4.0%20File%20Paths/chipkali.gif" alt="Your Image Alt Text" />
  <input className="inputFeild" placeholder="Email Id" />
</div>
```

Comment: yes, it's scss code.

Comment: I have given all solutions as per need for SCSS or CSS just see step 2 and step 3.

Comment: It's not working completly. see, the inputbox-container max-height will be 25% of the display. The image size should be the 80% of the 25% of inputbox-container. But with this code the image is still occupying more space.